# How To Retrieve Custom Columns For DriveItems in MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to use the Graph API to retrieve a hierarchy of files in a Sharepoint document library. Since document libraries are stored in "drives" (is it technically correct to call it OneDrive?), I'm using the `/drives` endpoint to fetch a list of files, like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveid}/root/children
```

I would like to get information from some of the custom columns that exist when viewing these items through Sharepoint. Using `?expand=fields` doesn't work because `fields` only exists in listItem object of the `/sites` endpoint, not in the `driveItem` object of `/drives` endpoint. If I try obtaining the listItem from a single driveItem (traversing the Graph from OneDrive to Sharepoint), and then expanding the fields, like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveid}/items/{driveItemId}/listItem?expand=fields
```

this retrieves built-in columns (Author, DocIcon, and some others) but doesn't seem to retrieve the custom columns.
I've also tried getting the list of files from the `/sites` endpoint, and using `?expand=fields` will get the custom columns, but it gets every file from every subfolder, rather than the current folder path. But I feel that deserves its own SO question.

Is it possible to retrieve custom column information from driveItems?

Comment: What are the values of `field.Hidden` and `field.ShowInDisplayForm` for your custom columns?

Comment: Being fairly new to Sharepoint Online, I'm not sure how to check these using the web-based front end. Using Graph Explorer, I can see that Hidden=false, but there is no ShowInDisplayForm value. Also, Indexed=false, ReadOnly=false, and Required=false, if those help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing.  What SHOULD work is:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{driveid}/root/children?$select=id,MyCustomColumnName`

However, when I did that, it just returned that id field. In my opinion, that is a bug in the graph because this same type of query does work in the SharePoint REST api.

If this helps, you can accomplish this by using the SharePoint REST api.  Your endpoint query would be something like:

`https://{yoursite}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/_api/web/lists/(' {DocumentLibraryID}')/items?$select=id,MyCustomColumnName`

There are other ways to do the same query.

Comment: It does feel like a bug. Hopefully someone from MSFT can chime in and give something more official. Maybe it's just not implemented yet, and will be coming in a future version of Graph API. I guess I'll be using SharePoint API until I hear otherwise.

Comment: In trying to stay on the Graph API, I ended up querying the Drives API to also select the Sharepoint ID of the file `/drives/{driveId}/root/children?select=sharepointIds,name` and then using that Sharepoint List Item ID on the Sites API `/sites/root/sites/{sitePath}/lists/{listId}/items/{listItemId}?expand=fields&select=fields`

Comment: It's not a bug, because the custom field is not a property on the driveItem object (in the query that selects a non-existent property, that property is silently ignored). The custom field (ie value for a column as seen in SharePoint) is a SharePoint specific concept so can be seen by expanding the fields of the SharePoint item, as others have said.

Answer (score 9):

I spent a lot of time digging around with the different syntax possibilities and was finally able to get custom library properties using this query format. This is the only one that has produced my custom/user-defined fields for a document library.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/insert_drive_id_here/root/children?expand=listItem

Shortened result:

```
{
"@odata.context": "...",
"value": [
        {
        "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "...",
        "listItem@odata.context": "...",
        "listItem": {
            "@odata.etag": "...",
            "fields@odata.context": "...",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "...",
                "Title": "...",
                "Other_Custom_Property": "..."
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks you saved my life the other solution is to using the standard sharepoint api instead of graph api

Answer (score 2):

Try the list endpoint then expand driveItem and fields. You now have both custom column fields and drive item fields.

```
 /beta/sites/[site-id]/lists/[list-id]/items?expand=driveitem,fields&filter=(fields/customColumn eq 'someValue')
```

Comment: Yes, this does work to retrieve the custom columns, but unfortunately it retrieves all items in the document library rather than just what's in a specified folder . With a large document library containing many nested subfolders, it would save a lot of bandwidth if it were possible to only retrieve the desired subfolder with no forced recursion.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody trying to get this to work in C# using the Graph client this is how I got it to work.

```
        var allSites = await _graphServiceClient.Sites.GetAllSites.GetAsync();
        var selectedSiteId = allSites.Value.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DisplayName.Equals("some name of site")).Id;
        var drive = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[selectedSiteId].Drive.GetAsync();
        var driveItems = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items["root"].Children.GetAsync();
        var documentsFolderId = driveItems.Value.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Equals("Documents")).Id; // Could also be another name for you
        var files = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[documentsFolderId].Children.GetAsync();
        var file = await _graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[documentsFolderId].ItemWithPath(files.Value.First().Name).ListItem.GetAsync();
        var allFields = file.Fields.AdditionalData; // this also contains the custom columns
```