# Add sharepoint custom field using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I want to upload my documents to my SharePoint site using Graph API. I followed the instruction in these posts and I'm able to upload my docs to Sharepoint site.

[How to create SharePoint list item with Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851894/how-to-create-sharepoint-list-item-with-microsoft-graph-api)

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content

However, I want to update some values of uploaded documents in the Document Library items but I cannot find any document to do that. Please advise me in this situation.

[image]

Notice: I found the solution by this post.
[How To Retrieve Custom Columns For DriveItems in MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166662/how-to-retrieve-custom-columns-for-driveitems-in-ms-graph)

Comment: Can you post your solution?  I don't see how you can update the values in the post that you linked.

Comment: I'm using graph client and this is my solutions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lLgZDAtmtPTHn1JweP-essTygaWU5jFY/view?usp=sharing